# Container con 100% height

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy buscando y mirando en distintos sitios, pero no consigo hacer que el container pille el 100% de la altura de la página.

- HTML

```
<html>
     <head>
          <!-- Importamos hojas de estilos de CSS -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <!-- Importamos una hoja de estilos personalizada, que sobreescribirá los archivos de bootstrap. -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom.css">
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class="container" id="dContent">
            <!-- Contenido -->
            >>> Aquí por ahora solo hay una navBar.
        </div>

<!--Por aquí estarían los Links para importar scripts de bootstrap>

    </body>
</html>
```

Por ahora este es el CSS que me ha quedado después de intentar varias cosas.

- Custom CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}

/* Se establece que el HTML ocupará el 100% de la página */
html {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Color de background */
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #000105 ;
}

/* Contenido */
#dContent{
    background-color: #04071D;
    padding: 0;
}
```

- **Al final, lo que estoy intentando es que me quede un container en el centro de la página que tenga un 10% de márgen por cada lado, dejando el body con un color de fondo y el container con otro, ocupando el container el 100% de la página.**

[image: Imagen de cómo quisiera que quede el layout.]

Comment: Prueba a agregar al id dContent min-height:100vh;

Comment: @PabloLozano sí, sí.